# How to avoid calling same javascript files multiple times when DOM content is loaded on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I know multiple post have already been posted on the similar topic, but I am yet to find a good answer on this. So, asking Gurus to help me out.

I am working on an application where I am working on *JavaScript*, and *JSF*. On page load I am calling multiple external javascript/jquery files (for multiple purposes) and they seems to work fine. However, there are couple of pages where I have some components (JSF components) that does not load initially or does not become part of the initial DOM (when page loads). However, when it load after some click event on the page (so i said content is loaded on the fly), then the new content does not get the javaScript/jquery effect.

Here's a brief example just to make my question more simple:

**I have this on the page header :**

**.. and this on the body**

```
<div class="panel">
   <p>some sample text</p>
   <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">Modify</a></p>
</div>
```

*(On the above code output,i get round shaped buttons for "Modify" text)*

*When someone clicks the modify button(link), then  gets the following codes:*

```
<div class="panel">
   <p>Do You want to modify</p>
   <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">Yes</a></p>   
   <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">No</a></p>
</div>
```

However, I do not get same rounded shape buttons anymore for "Yes" and "No". (And calling JQuery files on the bottom of the page doesn't help either).

**Through JSF we are using:**

```
<h:panelGroup render=.....>
   <div class="panel">
      <p>some sample text</p>
      <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">Modify</a></p>
   </div>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup render=.....>
   <div class="panel">
     <p>Do You want to modify</p>
     <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">Yes</a></p>   
     <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">No</a></p>
   </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So when the first panelGroup (JSF) gets loaded it gets what's on the header and load the javaScript and displays the buttons with the curveycorner, but when the second panel is loaded, it does not get the javascript.

**One solution I have is the following:**

```
<h:panelGroup render=.....>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.curvycorners.min.js"></script>

   <div class="panel">
     <p>Do You want to modify</p>
     <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">Yes</a></p>   
     <p class="button"><a href="javascript:fucntion">No</a></p>
   </div>

</h:panelGroup>
```

It works, but checking if there's a better option since we want to avoid calling the same javaScript file multiple times.

---

**Added the followings after I got some comments from others -** 
Actually i was wrong. Curvy corner plugin is a stand alone and does not need any other javascript/jquery file except for "curvycorners.js" .  Just incase if you guys stlil have doubt about it (or about my javascript knowledge), just try the following code and see how  'curvy corner" works (please download the "curvycorners.js" from http://www.curvycorners.net/ or anywhere else ..and then try my code , it's small and simple --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>curvyCorners - Tab demo</title>

<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
/* styles for the demo sub-pages */
#demo-btn {margin: 0.5in auto;border: 0px solid #fff;color: #fff; padding:5px 15px; text-align: center; background-color: #006354; 
border: 1px solid #ccc;  background-image: url(btn_middle_brnd.png);  background-repeat: repeat-x; border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; height:15px; width:80px; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;}
#demo-btn a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}  
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../curvycorners.src.js"> </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="demo-btn">
        <span><a href="javascript:function();">Cancel</a></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the complete event of the load or ajax method to apply the curvycorners plugin to elements that don't have it but need it.

```
$(el).load("url",function(){
  $(el).find('selector').corner();
});
```

**Added explanation:**

You didn't give us any JavaScript to look at, so all we can do is assume.

The corner plugin needs a particular piece of code to apply it to elements.

```
$(selector).corner();
```

In order for it to apply to an element, the element has to exist on the page when that piece of code is ran. Since you are loading the elements in with ajax, you will need to run that code again every time you run an ajax call so that it will apply to the new elements.

Comment: I agree that this is the solution but maybe make it a bit clearer and add some more explanations. Judging by the question it's hard to know if the person asking, will have enough understanding of Javascript to understand the answer.

Comment: I gave the following two javaScript ... one is just the basic JQuery file and the other one is a pluggin that could be found from google search or here http://www.curvycorners.net  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.curvycorners.min.js"></script>

Comment: Right, but including those two files alone shouldn't actually do anything.

Comment: i added more text above (under my original question) .. hope that helps. Please note that rounded/curvy corner is not my problem here. My problem is different. It can happen to anything ... datepick, tabs etc . My point was when a part of the 'content' is not loaded initially but loaded later, then anypart of it that requires some javascript to work with, does not work unless javascript is included inside that 'on the fly content'

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to dissect without seeing the jquery files, but my guess you aren't using delegates for components that aren't loaded when the page first loads. Check out here:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: How do you suggest he use `delegate` to apply the curvy corners plugin?